# Using searchtweets (‘academic research account)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I’ve been trying to use the package searchtweets-v2 without success.

When I type:

```
from searchtweets import load_credentials

load_credentials(filename="./search_tweets_creds_example.yaml",
                 yaml_key="search_tweets_v2_example",
                 env_overwrite=False)
```

The output says:

```
cannot read file ./search_tweets_creds_example.yaml
Error parsing YAML file; searching for valid environment variables
```

Any help please?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Also, you have a a yaml file and have you added your keys to the correct section of the file?

Comment: Actually I solved it: whitespace is syntax in YAML and goes wrong often. It was the case in my code.